# Is there a better way to get XmlReader NodeType properties?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.nodetype.aspx), it looks like each time I want to get a node element name, or a text value or whatever, I need to use switch-case.

So do I have to use something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
        nodeName = reader.Name;
        break;
    }
}
```

or am I missing something and it could be made shorter and more elegant (I need to use XmlReader, and am not in position to use LINQ to XML)? The idea of having to use all this switch-case mess everywhere just to get these small bits of information is not very appealing to me. Thank you.

Comment: +1: for all the valid points mentioned. I myself would like to know if a better solution exists. Based on my experience, I am using a Library that implements the same using switch,case. It was written by experienced group of developers. This leads me to believe that maybe the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no casting beeing done, so as far as i can see you can just go:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    nodeName = reader.Name;
}
```

I believes nodes always have a name atleast, i might be wrong though, but afaik they do.

Comment: Yup, it works, thanks. I tried that before but I wasn't aware that Element and Text and whatever are treated as a separate "Read()" so that's why it didn't work.. I thought that one Read() gets both tag and what's inside the tag but that's not the case.. So one Read() for the tag name, and then another one for the text value inside..

Answer (score 0):

The one thing about the Switch case is that it's very clear about your intentions, which I believe is an important thing in modern programming.

However, if you're tired of writing it all the time, and I can't blame you, what about wrapping it in an Extension method ?